# Media Queries behaving differently for each Browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser, media-queries

I'm working on a simple institutional website and all works well, except for the media queries. I'm new to this technology so I don't really know whats going on.

My issue appears when I open the collapsed bootstrap menu on iPad like screens and smaller and it depends on the browser.

It works fine for Firefox and has some issues with Chrome and Safari, so it makes me believe that my code is working, but I am missing some important aspects of browser compatibility.

I want the navbar menu to open with a gray background when the screen is medium size (only works for Firefox) and black for mobile (Safari has a bug which opens the whole menu and them cuts it by half).

This is the website: [flowersforpeaceproject.com](http://flowersforpeaceproject.com)

And here is the code:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
}

/*NAVBAR*/

.navbar{
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a{
    color: #1E73BE;
}

.navbar-default{
    background-color: transparent;
}

nav .navbar-brand img{
    height: 220px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

/*MEDIA QUERIES*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar-header {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
      display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
      top: 0;
      border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in{
      display:block !important;
  }

  /*MY CODE*/
  #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 .navbar-right{
      background-color: rgb(50,50,50, 0.9);
      border-radius: 10px;
      max-width: 180px;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    nav .navbar-brand img{
        height: 120px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 .navbar-right{
        border: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        width: 700px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        background-color: black;
        border-radius: 10px;

    }

}
/*END MEDIA*/

...
```

Answer (score 0):

### There's an good Resource available for learning and playing with media querys. [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

- Since this is an Browser based media query bug you can easily **solved by specifying different CSS to each screen resolutions.
  Here is an good tool to generate media Query. [Open Site.](https://tools.nasqueron.org/css/media-queries-generator)**

in your code you can generate css, for example for different Screen Resolutions.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    border: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 10;
            width: 700px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            background-color: black;
            border-radius: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 720px) {
    border: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 10;
            width: 700px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            background-color: black;
            border-radius: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 721px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
    border: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 10;
            width: 700px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            background-color: black;
            border-radius: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1281px) and (max-width: 1440px) {
    border: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 10;
            width: 700px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            background-color: black;
            border-radius: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1441px) and (max-width: 1920px) {
    border: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 10;
            width: 700px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            background-color: black;
            border-radius: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1921px) {
    border: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 10;
            width: 700px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            background-color: black;
            border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I've spent a long time looking at it and it is not a CSS thing (unless my CSS file has a typo, which I didn't find). For some reason it works perfectly in Firefox, but not in Chrome and Safari. I've  seen something about nested media queries, but my queries are not nested. I do have viewport meta set up on my HTML.